# Identifying Excel Sheet cell color code using XLRD package

Tags: python, excel, xlrd

I am writing a python script to read data from an excel sheet using [xlrd](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd). Few of the cells of the the work sheet are highlighted with different color and I want to identify the color code of the cell. Is there any way to do that ? An example would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Here is one way to handle this:

```
import xlrd
book = xlrd.open_workbook("sample.xls", formatting_info=True)
sheets = book.sheet_names()
print "sheets are:", sheets
for index, sh in enumerate(sheets):
    sheet = book.sheet_by_index(index)
    print "Sheet:", sheet.name
    rows, cols = sheet.nrows, sheet.ncols
    print "Number of rows: %s   Number of cols: %s" % (rows, cols)
    for row in range(rows):
        for col in range(cols):
            print "row, col is:", row+1, col+1,
            thecell = sheet.cell(row, col)      
            # could get 'dump', 'value', 'xf_index'
            print thecell.value,
            xfx = sheet.cell_xf_index(row, col)
            xf = book.xf_list[xfx]
            bgx = xf.background.pattern_colour_index
            print bgx
```

More info on the [Python-Excel Google Group](http://groups.google.com/group/python-excel/browse_thread/thread/1a03ada4f393faee/9e4354917efb7f40).

Comment: The script is able to identify color code. But now I am getting a different problem. The excel sheet which I am parsing has two empty cells without any extra formatting or color, that is, both of the cells has white background and no text inside, at the position - (52,4) and (9,4). In first case, color is 64 and the for the other one it is 9. How is the color code different for two similar type of cells?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have one `blank` and another `no fill`?

Comment: Colour index 9 means white unless the palette has been changed. 61 is a "system" colour index; read the section about colour indexes near the start of the xlrd docs. "empty", "white" and "no text inside" are vague. Tell us the cell **type**, value, and xf_index. Use `repr(value)`. You may have default formatting applied to column 4; what does `sheet.colinfo_map[4].xf_index` give you?

Comment: I finally managed to differentiate if a cell is highlighted or not. The check is done by finding cell’s color map.

Here is the code: 

book = xlrd.open_workbook("sample.xls", formatting_info=1)
xfx = sheet.cell_xf_index(row, col)
xf = book.xf_list[xfx]
bgx = xf.background.pattern_colour_index
color_map = book.colour_map[bgx]

if color_map and (color_map[0] != 255 or color_map[1] != 255 or color_map[2] != 255):
   #worksheet Cell is highlighted
else:
   #worksheet Cell is not highlighted

So, if none of values in tuple is 255, that means the cell is highlighted.

Comment: This raises a `NotImplementedError` at me. Likely because I open `xlsx` rather than `xls`: `NotImplementedError: formatting_info=True not yet implemented`

Comment: Unfortunately, this works only for 'XLS' files, not for 'XLSX' files. Does anybody have any solution to 'XLSX' files ? You will get a 'NotImplementedError'.

Answer (score 9):

The Solution suggested by JMax works only for `xls` file, not for `xlsx` file. This raises a `NotImplementedError: formatting_info=True not yet implemented`. `Xlrd` library is still not updated to work for `xlsx` files. So you have to `Save As` and change the format every time which may not work for you. 
 
Here is a solution for `xlsx` files using `openpyxl` library. `A2` is the cell whose color code we need to find out.

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook
excel_file = 'color_codes.xlsx' 
wb = load_workbook(excel_file, data_only = True)
sh = wb['Sheet1']
color_in_hex = sh['A2'].fill.start_color.index # this gives you Hexadecimal value of the color
print ('HEX =',color_in_hex) 
print('RGB =', tuple(int(color_in_hex[i:i+2], 16) for i in (0, 2, 4))) # Color in RGB
```

Comment: @Heinz I tested it for multiple cases, by changing a lot of colors. It worked just fine. Can you share your example ?

Comment: In my case it raises `TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable` because color_in_hex is just a number like 6 or 7 (even though the colors are completely different like yellow and grey, how can they be two numbers next to each other?) and it's an integer, which is not a subscritable type, thus [i:i+2] cannot be executed. I tried to align it with `color_in_hex: str = f"#{str(color_in_hex).zfill(6)}"` to get something like `#000007` but the color is incorrect anyway

Answer (score 5):

This function returns cell background's rgb value in tuple.

```
def getBGColor(book, sheet, row, col):
    xfx = sheet.cell_xf_index(row, col)
    xf = book.xf_list[xfx]
    bgx = xf.background.pattern_colour_index
    pattern_colour = book.colour_map[bgx]

    #Actually, despite the name, the background colour is not the background colour.
    #background_colour_index = xf.background.background_colour_index
    #background_colour = book.colour_map[background_colour_index]

    return pattern_colour
```

Comment: This is for the xlrd, with ` open_workbook(..., formatting_info=True)` so it can't be used with xlsx files.

Answer (score 0):

```
# say you have an Excel file called workbook
 and inside it there is a worksheet called worksheet

# inside that worksheet is cell say C1 that is highlighted
 and you want to get the color value of the highlighted cell

# Trying the openpyxl package
import openpyxl

# Importing all modules from the openpyxl package
from openpyxl import *

# reading ev2 excel workbook through load_workbook function
workbook = load_workbook("C:PATHTO/workbook.xlsx")

# Accessing existing worksheets
worksheet = workbook ["worksheet"]

## METHOD1 ##

# Getting the highlight property of the cell
highlight=str(worksheet ['C1'].fill)

# Printing out the value of the color
index=int(highlight.find("rgb='"))
print(highlight[index+5:index+13])

## METHOD 2 ##

print(worksheet ['C11'].fill.start_color.index)
```