# How to get Excel cell properties in Python

Tags: python, xlrd

Actually I am using xlrd module 0.8 version, but I don't know how to read cell properties like background color, font, and whether cell is locked.

I tried to use

```
import xlrd
wb = xlrd.open_workbook(...)
sh = wb.sheet_by_index(...)
sh.sh._cell_xf_indexes(2, 2)
```

It raises an error saying formatting information needs to be set while reading `wb`, but if I had that parameter then it shows it is still not implemented.

Is there another module or how can this module itself be made to read cell properties?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7991209/identifying-excel-sheet-cell-color-code-using-xlrd-package

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The following works for me, using xlrd version 0.7.6:

```
from xlrd import open_workbook

wb = open_workbook('tmp.xls', formatting_info=True)
sheet = wb.sheet_by_name("1")
cell = sheet.cell(6, 0)
print "cell.xf_index is", cell.xf_index
fmt = wb.xf_list[cell.xf_index]
print "type(fmt) is", type(fmt)
print
print "fmt.dump():"
fmt.dump()
```

`fmt` is an instance of the XF class; see https://secure.simplistix.co.uk/svn/xlrd/trunk/xlrd/doc/xlrd.html#formatting.XF-class

The `dump()` method prints all the information about the format. Here's the output of the above code:

```
cell.xf_index is 497
type(fmt) is <class 'xlrd.formatting.XF'>

fmt.dump():
_alignment_flag: 1
_background_flag: 1
_border_flag: 1
_font_flag: 1
_format_flag: 0
_protection_flag: 0
alignment (XFAlignment object):
    hor_align: 1
    indent_level: 0
    rotation: 0
    shrink_to_fit: 0
    text_direction: 0
    text_wrapped: 0
    vert_align: 2
background (XFBackground object):
    background_colour_index: 64
    fill_pattern: 1
    pattern_colour_index: 17
border (XFBorder object):
    bottom_colour_index: 0
    bottom_line_style: 0
    diag_colour_index: 0
    diag_down: 0
    diag_line_style: 0
    diag_up: 0
    left_colour_index: 0
    left_line_style: 0
    right_colour_index: 0
    right_line_style: 0
    top_colour_index: 56
    top_line_style: 1
font_index: 72
format_key: 0
is_style: 0
lotus_123_prefix: 0
parent_style_index: 0
protection (XFProtection object):
    cell_locked: 1
    formula_hidden: 0
xf_index: 497
```

Some of those values are indices into lists on the workbook `wb`.  For example, `fmt.font_index` is 72, and `wb.font_list[72]` is an instance of the `Font` class (https://secure.simplistix.co.uk/svn/xlrd/trunk/xlrd/doc/xlrd.html#formatting.Font-class).

Comment: what if you are using an xlsx file? format_info is not implemented

Comment: @Boosted_d16, if this Q&A are not relevant to the case of using an xlsx file, then you could ask a new stackoverflow question.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! Note that `formatting_info=True` only works for xls type (refer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13892307/python-xlutils-formatting-info-true-not-yet-implemented)).

Comment: Can the similar things be done with openpyxl?