# Reading strikethroughs in Excel with Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

Is there a way for me to read strikethroughs in Pandas without resorting to VBA? I have a spreadsheet where a person refuses to use anything else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't possible in Pandas but would be using [`xlrd`](http://www.python-excel.org/). You could first parse for formatting and then turn that into a Pandas dataframe.

Sample code to read a file using `xlrd`. Adapted the response to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12540856/how-to-get-excel-cell-properties-in-python):

```
import xlrd.open_workbook

workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('tmp.xls', formatting_info=True)
sheet = wb.sheet_by_name("1")
cell = sheet.cell(6, 0)
format = wb.xf_list[cell.xf_index]
print "type(format) is", type(format)
print
print "format.dump():"
format.dump()
```