# openpyxl: Issue reading $ and . from xlsx

Tags: python, excel, ubuntu-14.04, openpyxl

I want to convert an xlsx file to TAB delimited csv using python. After reading I was pointed to library called openpyxl (code below)

```
def importXLSX(fileName):
        temp = os.path.basename(fileName).split('.xlsx')
        tempFileName = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(fileName))+"/TEMP_"+temp[0]+".csv"
        tempFile = open(tempFileName,'w')
        wb = load_workbook(filename=fileName)
        ws = wb.worksheets[0] #Get first worksheet
        for row in ws.rows: #Iterate over rows
                for cell in row:
                        cellValue = "" 
                        if cell.value is not None:
                                cellValue = cell.value
                        tempFile.write(cellValue+'\t')
                tempFile.write('\n')
        os.remove(fileName)
        return tempFileName
```

The input file I have contains billing data, but this function is converting **$2,000** to **2000** and **0.00** to **0**

Any idea why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because in Excel when you set the format for a cell to  e.g. currency format so the value 2000 displays as $2000.00, you aren't changing the value in the cell, and openpyxl is reading the value in the cell, not its formatted/displayed presentation. if you had typed the string '$2000.00 in the cell then that's what openpyxl would see. Similarly for display format showing two decimal places, so 0 is displayed as 0.00, the *value* in the cell is still 0, so that's what openpyxl sees.

There are other questions on SO about reading cell formatting using the xlrd library instead of openpyxl: for example see [How to get Excel cell properties in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12540856/how-to-get-excel-cell-properties-in-python) and [Identifying Excel Sheet cell color code using XLRD package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7991209/identifying-excel-sheet-cell-color-code-using-xlrd-package) and in general google *python excel read cell format*