# How to read formated cell display of datetime using python

Tags: python, excel, datetime, format, cell

I have the excel cell with the format: [>=1] dd hh:mm:ss; hh:mm:ss

When python reads it, it just reads the cell value but not the cell display format.

I want to read the cell display format with which the excel configured.

Can anyone provide me a solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get Excel cell properties in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12540856/how-to-get-excel-cell-properties-in-python).

Comment: You have to convert it into datetime format once you import it into python.

Comment: This is still blocking me, Could anyone please help me out from this?