# python looping through excel documents losing excel document data after changing set properties

Tags: python, excel

Need help looping through a directory full of xlsx and xlsm documents and changing set_properties.
I have roughly 10k excel files (xlsx & xlsm, no xls files). I am trying to loop through them and change the set_properties.
The code I have written makes the correct changes to all documents however when I try to open the documents, all the content (all sheets and everything in each worksheet) is gone. 
Thanks for your help!

```
import os
from openpyxl import Workbook
import xlsxwriter
import datetime

os.chdir('C:\\Users\\bayli\\Desktop\\unscrubbed')

mydate = datetime.datetime.now()    
files_not_scrubbed = 0

for filename in os.listdir():

if filename.endswith(".xlsx") or filename.endswith(".XLSX") or 
filename.endswith(".xlsm") or filename.endswith(".XLSM"):
    currentBook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(filename)
    currentBook.set_properties({
        'title':    'TEST',
        'subject':  'TEST',
        'author':   'TEST',
        'manager':  'TEST',
        'company':  'TEST',
        'category': 'TEST',
        'keywords': 'TEST',
        'comments': 'TEST',
        'status':   'TEST',
        'create':   mydate,
    })
    currentBook.close()
else:
    files_not_scrubbed = files_not_scrubbed + 1
    continue    

print("There were " + str(files_not_scrubbed) + " files not scrubbed.")
```

Answer (score 0):

xlsxwriter creates a new workbook with new property. Try to use openpyxl as shown in that [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52120125/how-to-edit-core-properties-of-xlsx-file-with-python)