# Python / Excel - Conditional cell printing with xlrd

Tags: python, excel, xlrd

I want to print only the rows of a specifig column, let's say colmn B, so far so good:

```
import xlrd
file_location = "/home/myuser/excel.xls"
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(file_location)
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
data = [[sheet.cell_value(r, c) for c in range(sheet.ncols)] for r in range(sheet.nrows)]

for r in data:
    print r[1]
```

Now I want to print out only those cell values, which have a yellow colored background.
I found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7991209/identifying-excel-sheet-cell-color-code-using-xlrd-package#) but failed to adept it to my code. Could anybody help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the specific color index of the cells with yellow background, you can check the `background.pattern_colour_index` value of the cell style. Note that it is important to pass `formatting_info=True` to the `open_workbook()`:

```
import xlrd

file_location = "/home/myuser/excel.xls"
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(file_location, formatting_info=True)
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)

for row in range(sheet.nrows):
    cell = sheet.cell(row, 1)
    style = workbook.xf_list[cell.xf_index]
    color = style.background.pattern_colour_index
    if color == 43:  # on of yellows
        print cell.value
```

---

Example:

For the file containing 2 cells with yellow background:

[image]

The code above prints:

```
test2
test4
```