# Get the color of a cell from xlsx with python

Tags: python, excel

I am really new with python, but Iwould like to get the color of a given cell with python from a xlsx. I wore the part that reads the xlsx, but how can I continue it with getting the backgrond color of the A3 cell?

```
import xlrd

workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('67.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_name('Oldal1')
# read a cell
cell = worksheet.cell(2,2)
#print cell
print cell.value
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7991209/identifying-excel-sheet-cell-color-code-using-xlrd-package

Comment: Yes, I tried it, but it gives back the error: NotImplementedError: formatting_info=True not yet implemented

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Always a solution out there, somewhere in the deep ocean of SO:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7991209/identifying-excel-sheet-cell-color-code-using-xlrd-package)

```
def getBGColor(book, sheet, row, col):
    xfx = sheet.cell_xf_index(row, col)
    xf = book.xf_list[xfx]
    bgx = xf.background.pattern_colour_index
    pattern_colour = book.colour_map[bgx]

    #Actually, despite the name, the background colour is not the background colour.
    #background_colour_index = xf.background.background_colour_index
    #background_colour = book.colour_map[background_colour_index]

    return pattern_colour
```

[Oh, wait. this is even better!](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/openpyxl/styles/colors.html)

**EDIT**:

Here is a complete code:

```
from xlrd import open_workbook

wb = open_workbook('cel_lis.xls', formatting_info=True)
sh = wb.sheet_by_name('Sheet1')


def getBGColor(book, sheet, row, col):
    xfx = sheet.cell_xf_index(row, col)
    xf = book.xf_list[xfx]
    bgx = xf.background.pattern_colour_index
    pattern_colour = book.colour_map[bgx]

    #Actually, despite the name, the background colour is not the background colour.
    #background_colour_index = xf.background.background_colour_index
    #background_colour = book.colour_map[background_colour_index]

    return pattern_colour


print("The RGB value of the cell is: {}".format(getBGColor(wb, sh, 0, 0)))
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
The RGB value of the cell is: (255, 0, 0)
```

**Note**:

> I used a worksheet of type `.xls` with a name `cel_lis.xls` having its
>   sheet called `Sheet1` with the first cell `A` which has a `Red`
>   background color.

[image: out]

**EDIT 2**:

To get the `name` of the color, you could use `webcolors`:

```
from webcolors import rgb_to_name

rgb_Col = getBGColor(wb, sh, 0, 0)
print("The RGB value of the cell is: {} which is equivalent to {}".format(rgb_Col, rgb_to_name(rgb_Col)))
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
The RGB value of the cell is: (255, 0, 0) which is equivalent to red
```

Comment: do I have to define the workbook, worksheet, row and col in advance? Because it doesnt print out anything if it add print pattern_colour

Comment: @GyaNoLi Indeed, you do. Let me see If I can serve it better for you.

Comment: @GyaNoLi Kindly check the edit and if it helps please accept the answer: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work cheers

Comment: This won't work for XLSX file. It only works for XLS.

Answer (score 2):

The Solution previously suggested works only for `xls` file, not for `xlsx` file. This raises a `NotImplementedError: formatting_info=True not yet implemented`. `Xlrd` library is still not updated to work for `xlsx` files. So you have to `Save As` and change the format every time which may not work for you. 
Here is a solution for `xlsx` files using `openpyxl` library. `A2` is the cell whose color code we need to find out.

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook
excel_file = 'color_codes.xlsx' 
wb = load_workbook(excel_file, data_only = True)
sh = wb['Sheet1']
color_in_hex = sh['A2'].fill.start_color.index # this gives you Hexadecimal value of the color
print ('HEX =',color_in_hex) 
print('RGB =', tuple(int(color_in_hex[i:i+2], 16) for i in (0, 2, 4))) # Color in RGB
```