# Python - read cells color from xlsx file with conditional formatting

Tags: python, excel, xlsx

I need to get cell colors from excel with conditional formatting.
Cells are colored with conditional formatting rules, so I cannot read the background color directly, as it's always 00000000. Tried libraries: openpyxl and pandas.

Comment: Does something like this work? https://stackoverflow.com/a/7991458/1835727

Answer (score 0):

The fill value of a conditionally formatted cell can be read using the VBA function:

```
Range("B2") = Range("A2").DisplayFormat.Interior.Color
```

where A2 is the formatted (source) cell and B2 is the target cell in which you want the colour value.

I have found the returned decimal needs a bit of handling. For example, primary colour values such as RGB 255,0,0 only return 255, which gives no indication whether it's 0,255,0, or 0,0,255, and also where a conversion to hex results in leading or trailing zeros.

You can solve this by:

1. Wrapping a Hex() around the code (caution, this results in something apparently called a twisted pair, whereby the outside hex values are in reverse order eg C3B2A1. They can be swapped round to A1B2C3 with a quick shuffle)
2. Wrapping Right("000000" & code), 6) around the above.

This gives you the three pair hex value you can then use:

```
rev_hex_fill = Right("000000" & Hex(Range("A2").DisplayFormat.Interior.Color), 6)
 
rev_hex_fill = Right(rev_hex_fill, 2) & Mid(rev_hex_fill, 3, 2) & Left(rev_hex_fill, 2)
 
Range("B2") = rev_hex_fill
```

You can do the same with font colour, but you don't need the DisplayFormat part - you can just use Range("A2").Font.Color.

The below code loops, reads, and displays up to 100 conditionally formatted fill and font colours (B3:B103), which might be useful.

```
Sub getcol()

    For Row = 3 To 102
    
    Source = ("B" & Row)
    
    fill_cell = ("D" & Row)
    Range(fill_cell).Interior.Color = Range(Source).DisplayFormat.Interior.Color
    
    fill_text = ("E" & Row)
    Range(fill_text).Font.Color = Range(Source).DisplayFormat.Interior.Color
    
    font_fill = ("F" & Row)
    Range(font_fill).Interior.Color = Range(Source).Font.Color
    
    font_text = ("G" & Row)
    Range(font_text).Font.Color = Range(Source).Font.Color
    
    full_copy = ("H" & Row)
    Range(full_copy).Interior.Color = Range(Source).DisplayFormat.Interior.Color
    Range(full_copy).Font.Color = Range(Source).Font.Color
    Range(full_copy) = Range(fill_text)
    
    fill_dec = ("I" & Row)
    Range(fill_dec) = Range(Source).DisplayFormat.Interior.Color
    
    fill_hex = ("J" & Row)
    rev_hex_fill = Right("000000" & Hex(Range(Source).DisplayFormat.Interior.Color), 6)
    rev_hex_fill = Right(rev_hex_fill, 2) & Mid(rev_hex_fill, 3, 2) & Left(rev_hex_fill, 2)
    Range(fill_hex) = rev_hex_fill
    
    font_dec = ("K" & Row)
    Range(font_dec) = Range(Source).Font.Color
    
    font_hex = ("L" & Row)
    rev_hex_text = Right("000000" & Hex(Range(Source).Font.Color), 6)
    rev_hex_text = Right(rev_hex_text, 2) & Mid(rev_hex_text, 3, 2) & Left(rev_hex_text, 2)
    Range(font_hex) = rev_hex_text
              
    Next
        
End Sub
```